# How to run an application that uses aws Service Discovery locally?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, microservices, service-discovery

I'm currently trying to create an application that have some separated micros-services and they need to communicate between them.
The problem is: I want to deploy the complete application to aws, using ECS, ECR, and mainly using AWS Service Discovery.
The application runs ok on the cloud, but how to run it locally?
My initial thoughts tends towards something like choosing between using the Service Discovery when on the cloud or using something like Eureka locally.